# 403 Forbidden on Sub-Folders

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd, php, selinux

I decided to do a LAMP install to start getting more familiar with it (as our company is moving more towards nix these days). Everything went great and PHPMyAdmin, MySQL, Apache/PHP all seem to be running fine.

The test `.php` files I uploaded to the `/var/www/html` directory worked fine, but after extracting a tarball with a folder inside of it to that directory, I receive a `403 Forbidden` error when attempting to access it.

I have tried...

- Setting SELinux to permissive mode
- CHMOD directory to 777 for testing. It fixes the 403 error but all the php files in it are just white pages
- Setting a  in the Apache configuration

The httpd error_log reports (before I set it to permissive)...

```
SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run:

> restorecon -r /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have a `.htaccess` file inside that archive, which causes that error.
If it's default configuration, then you should have more information in error log about 403.